# Google Maps API v3, lots of markers, clustering and performance

Tags: performance, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, cluster-analysis

I have about 5000 markers I need to render on Google Map. I'm currently using the API (v3) and there are performance issues on slower machines, especially in IE. I have done the following already to help speed things up:

1. Used a simple marker class that extends OverlayView and renders a single DIV element per marker
2. Implemented the MarkerClusterer library to cluster the markers at different levels
3. Render GIFs for IE, instead of alpha PNGs

Are there faster clustering classes? Any other tips? I'm trying to avoid server-side clustering unless this is the only option left to squeeze performance out of the system.

Thanks

Comment: I presume you have read http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/toomanymarkers.html especially FusionTablesLayer

Comment: I'm using the MarkerClusterer library from that page. IE6 performance is still atrocious when rendering a lot of things on the map (even when clustered) and I'm really looking for ways to improve that particular browser.

Comment: I know this is old but, how many users do you have that use IE6?

Comment: http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/ compares different libraries & their performance (kind of benchmark)

Comment: Check out MarkerClustererPlus.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used a method that loads all the markers onto the page, and then listens for the map to finish panning.

When the map has finished panning, I first check the zoom level - if it's too high I don't display anything. If it's at an acceptable level, I then loop through the markers I have stored and see if they fall into the bounding box of the map. If they do, they get added. A second loop then removes any that have moved out of the view.

The highest number I've used is about 30,000 markers with this method, although I have it so you must be zoomed in quite far to see them. In areas of higher concentration of markers it's obviously a little slower but it's useable.

Answer (score 0):

The solution mentioned above works for much higher number of markers. We use it for millions of GPS points at backend (including polygons etc). The only problem is some logic behind like proper caching of spatial queries, or fetching new results only, if user moves a map for more than X meters. There is a lot of work to make it done, but  for viewing real high number of points, there is nothing better.

Marker clusteres are usually working at browser side, so these is still need to load all points at once - and this makes this method unusable for large numbers.

You can check it out at http://www.tixik.com/london-2354567.htm live (just click ,,plan a trip " and start planning. Just try to move a map, zoom in or out and all points will show/hide on map zoom/drag.

Comment: answers do not have a fixed order, a comment seems to be the more appropriate form for your text

Comment: too long by 171 characters